# Struggling with Pivot synta

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, pivot

Hi can someone tell me what is the error in this sample pivot command

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
 SELECT *
  FROM issued

 ) Src
 PIVOT
( SUM(quantity)  
FOR team IN (production,wastage,staff)
) AS Pvt;
```

Comment: post your schema and expected result.

Comment: Not surprised there is no pivot on mysql - search msql pivot for alternatives Or if you are using sqlserver change the tags

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Comment: MySQL doesn't support `pivot`.  Follow Yogesh's advice and use conditional aggregation -- regardless of the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do *conditional* aggregation instead :

```
select col,
       sum(case when team = 'Production' then qty else 0 end) as production_qty,
       sum(case when team = 'wastage' then qty else 0 end) as wastage_qty,
       sum(case when team = 'staff' then qty else 0 end) as staff_qty
from issued
group by col --- use actual column name if any
```